# string crypt error dcpcrypt Lazarus

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

Can anybody say please why this does not crypt/decrypt strings? It only crypts them but no way back to written text:

```
procedure TForm1.btnEncryptClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
    i: integer;
    Cipher: TDCP_rc4;
    KeyStr: string;
  begin
    KeyStr:= '';
    if InputQuery('Passphrase','Enter passphrase',KeyStr) then  // get the passphrase
    begin
      Cipher:= TDCP_rc4.Create(Self);
      Cipher.InitStr(KeyStr,TDCP_sha1);         // initialize the cipher with a hash of the passphrase
      for i:= 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count-1 do       // encrypt the contents of the memo
        Memo1.Lines[i]:= Cipher.EncryptString(Memo1.Lines[i]);
      Cipher.Burn;
      Cipher.Free;
    end;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.btnDecryptClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
    i: integer;
    Cipher: TDCP_rc4;
    KeyStr: string;
  begin
    KeyStr:= '';
    if InputQuery('Passphrase','Enter passphrase',KeyStr) then  // get the passphrase
    begin
      Cipher:= TDCP_rc4.Create(Self);
      Cipher.InitStr(KeyStr,TDCP_sha1);         // initialize the cipher with a hash of the passphrase
      for i:= 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count-1 do       // decrypt the contents of the memo
        Memo1.Lines[i]:= Cipher.DecryptString(Memo1.Lines[i]);
      Cipher.Burn;
      Cipher.Free;
    end;
  end;
```

It is dcpcrypt library for Lazarus. The code is compiled without error, but no correct result in writeln procedure. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does the same code work with sha256 instead of sha1?

Comment: I do not know I ommited this lib It somehow did not work for me. Maybe anybody else can try the code. Thanks for the reply. I somehow do not understand clearly those things around ciphers - like what should be used where. But in sha1 mode I ciphered string and I tried to decipher it but got different source string. I used standard docs for this lib with above example.

Comment: I do not see any writeln. And BTW: it is almost always a bad idea to directly encrypt strings because this depends on the character encoding. Test your code with known test vectors. To verify the correct keys, manually compute and compare the hashes. Another source of problems is the storage of encrpyted strings in memos, richedits etc, this can result in loss of chars/bytes (especially the #0, #13, #10 etc)